# subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$, set of all invertible matrices over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ contain a cyclic subgroup of order $5$, where $\mathbb{R}$ = set of all real numbers?

Comment: It is a good question

Answer (score 5):

Hint: In any group, any element of order $5$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $5$. Can you think of an invertible linear transformation $T$ of the plane for which $T^5 = I$?

Comment: but then entries of the matrix will be complex numbers

Comment: Says who?$\mathstrut$

Comment: @chotonchoton I never said anything about matrices. I am talking about linear transformations. Granted, the two concepts are quite intimately connected. But one can reason about linear transformations much more intuitively than one can about matrices. And as long as you know that you send the plane to the plane, you know that the corresponding matrix has real entries.

Comment: actually if there exits a cyclic subgroup of order 5 then there is a invertible martix of order 2 whose order will be 5.But i am not getting any invertible matrix of order 2 whose order is 5

Comment: @chotonchoton You are using the word order for two different things here. The same matrix can't have order 2 and order 5. But more importantly, I'm trying to tell you to _stop thinking about matrices_. Think about linear transformations instead. What can you do to the plane so that if you do it five times in a row, you're back where you started?

Answer (score 2):

*Any* cyclic group can be regarded as a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$. Note that it is always good to regard matrices as linear transformations. For the finite cyclic groups, try to think about a linear transformation that gives you the identity transformation if you apply it for the finite times, say, $n$ times. (Think about the rotation.) For the infinite cyclic group, consider the following matrix:
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
How does this matrix act on the real plane $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and *why* this matrix has infinite order?